# unable to install pysensors 0.0.3 on python 2.7

Tags: python, installation, pip

I actually need to monitor some metrics from the Computer, like fan speed, CPU etc. So, i tried installing pysensors 0.0.3 through pip and manually. 
Getting the below error :

Manually :

```
C:\Python27\PySensors-0.0.3>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
import sensors
File "C:\Python27\PySensors-0.0.3\sensors\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
SENSORS_LIB = CDLL(LIB_FILENAME)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

PIP:

```
C:\Users\vermarahul>pip install pysensors
Collecting pysensors
Using cached PySensors-0.0.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "c:\users\vermar~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kqjh8i\pysensors\setu
p.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sensors
  File "sensors\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    SENSORS_LIB = CDLL(LIB_FILENAME)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\vermar~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kqjh8i\pysensors
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you did install `lm_sensors` before trying to install `pysensors`, right? I am not sure if `lm_sensors` is still under development, though. The official website seems to be down.

Comment: Actually no, i tried the lm_sensors, but as you said their website was down. :(